# Address family not supported by protocol while trying to run .Net application in AWS lambda

Tags: c#, .net, api, aws-lambda

I have followed steps in the following link https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/net-core-3-0-on-lambda-with-aws-lambdas-custom-runtime/ when i am trying to get information by sending a get request from post man it is throwing out error as "Address family not supported by protocal" the thing is i am not very sure whether i am missing something within the code or is it at AWS end

```json
{
    "resource": "/{proxy+}",
    "path": "/api/UmcCatalog",
    "httpMethod": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto": "https",
        "CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer": "true",
        "CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer": "false",
        "CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer": "false",
        "CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer": "false",
        "CloudFront-Viewer-Country": "IN",
        "Host": "81qy2.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com",
        "Postman-Token": "714505fe-df8a-4673-b0e1-10030c940a63",
        "User-Agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.21.0",
        "Via": "1.1 49a7052b1cf6cbcdc134f38b7efabee5.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)",
        "X-Amz-Cf-Id": "3FIUIXfLI7CVRXPZQixJJ-MMZz7UFQ-i3jZLaYYF5HOQNSw==",
        "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-5e147952-8d33a081f359a654180d56af",
        "X-Forwarded-For": "company IP",
        "X-Forwarded-Port": "443",
        "X-Forwarded-Proto": "https"
    },
    "multiValueHeaders": {
        "Accept": [
            "*/*"
        ],
        "Accept-Encoding": [
            "gzip, deflate"
        ],
        "Cache-Control": [
            "no-cache"
        ],
        "CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto": [
            "https"
        ],
        "CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer": [
            "true"
        ],
        "CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer": [
            "false"
        ],
        "CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer": [
            "false"
        ],
        "CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer": [
            "false"
        ],
        "CloudFront-Viewer-Country": [
            "IN"
        ],
        "Host": [
            "8a9ry2.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com"
        ],
        "Postman-Token": [
            "714505fe-df8a-4673-b0e1-10030c940a63"
        ],
        "User-Agent": [
            "PostmanRuntime/7.21.0"
        ],
        "Via": [
            "1.1 49a7056cbcdc134f38b7efabee5.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)"
        ],
        "X-Amz-Cf-Id": [
            "3FIUIX7CVRXPZQixJJ-MMZzARQr1Oj7UFQ-i3jZLaYYF5HOQNSw=="
        ],
        "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": [
            "Root=1-5e147952-8d33a0a654180d56af"
        ],
        "X-Forwarded-For": [
            "company IP"
        ],
        "X-Forwarded-Port": [
            "443"
        ],
        "X-Forwarded-Proto": [
            "https"
        ]
    },
    "queryStringParameters": null,
    "multiValueQueryStringParameters": null,
    "pathParameters": {
        "proxy": "api/UmcCatalog"
    },
    "stageVariables": null,
    "requestContext": {
        "resourceId": "tt4ts5",
        "resourcePath": "/{proxy+}",
        "httpMethod": "GET",
        "extendedRequestId": "F7fk2FrVyK4Fcow=",
        "requestTime": "07/Jan/2020:12:28:02 +0000",
        "path": "/Prod/api/UmcCatalog",
        "accountId": "xxxxxxx",
        "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
        "stage": "Prod",
        "domainPrefix": "81a9ry2",
        "requestTimeEpoch": 1578400082183,
        "requestId": "d37749bf-cd19-4cf3-9209-8befcc735154",
        "identity": {
            "cognitoIdentityPoolId": null,
            "accountId": null,
            "cognitoIdentityId": null,
            "caller": null,
            "sourceIp": "182.72.188.98",
            "principalOrgId": null,
            "accessKey": null,
            "cognitoAuthenticationType": null,
            "cognitoAuthenticationProvider": null,
            "userArn": null,
            "userAgent": "PostmanRuntime/7.21.0",
            "user": null
        },
        "domainName": "81qzy2.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com",
        "apiId": "81qzy2"
    },
    "body": null,
    "isBase64Encoded": false
}
```

My .NET code looks like this where i put lambda entry point

```
    `try{
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME")))
            {
                CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
                GlobalLogger.Current.Info("init main in program file");
            }
            else
            {
                var lambdaEntry = new LambdaEntryPoint();
                LambdaLogger.Log("entered entry point");
                var functionHandler = (Func<APIGatewayProxyRequest, ILambdaContext, 
                Task<APIGatewayProxyResponse>>)(lambdaEntry.FunctionHandlerAsync);
                using (var handlerWrapper = HandlerWrapper.GetHandlerWrapper(functionHandler, new 
                    Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer()))
                using (var bootstrap = new LambdaBootstrap(handlerWrapper))
                {
                    bootstrap.RunAsync().Wait();
                }

            }
            
        }`
```

I have removed original values for safety reasons . Any help is appreciated . Thank you

Comment: Please let me know if any one need any further info

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue after running a lambda function with a dotnet core 3.0 app deployed to it